# Why does replaceAll remove the numbers from the String?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

```
String foo = "a3#4#b";
String afterPunctutationRemoval = foo.replaceAll("[,.;:?!'-_\"/()\\{}]", "");
System.out.println(afterPunctutationRemoval);
```

it gives me "a##b" as a result, can someone explain me why?

Shouldn't it return the string as it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your character class contains the range `'`..`_` which matches digits as well.

Put the `-` at the start or end of the character class:

```
foo.replaceAll("[,.;:?!'_\"/()\\{}-]", "")
```

or escape it:

```
foo.replaceAll("[,.;:?!'\\-_\"/()\\{}]", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

`'-_` matches every character between `'` and `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other two people said, escape the `-` character - `\\-`.

Also, `\\{` evaluates to the same as `{`, was this intended?  If not, try escaping the backslash - `\\\\{`

Comment: also, that should return `""`.  The `.` character is supposed to evaluate to every character.